# Condense text without changing the indentation

Tags: python, grid

Within Python, I am trying to create a game which allows players to input a position on the grid and from their position a check is made for multiple instances and collecting x amount of a certain variable.

I have a function which allows the user to either uses an 8x8 grid or a 12x12. To generate the 12x12 grid, I have directly cut and copied by code from the 8x8 grid, changing the integers so it prints 12 rows and columns.

If the user selects the 8x8 grid the code prints perfectly:

```
-------------------------- 
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 
1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
2  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
3  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
4  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
5  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
6  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
7  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
8  0  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  
--------------------------
```

However, as the code is cut and pasted from the 8x8 grid when the 12x12 grid is generated as '10,11 and 12' are have two numbers the indentation makes the lower rows on the grid become mis-indented.

```
--------------------------------------- 
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12   
1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
2  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
3  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
4  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
5  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
6  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
7  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
8  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
9  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
10  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
11  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
12  0  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
---------------------------------------
```

Here is the sample code for generating my grid:

```
for i in range(-1+(coordinate[0])):
   print(length," . "*12)
   length=length+1
print(length," . "*((coordinate[1])-1),counter," . "*(11-coordinate[1]))
length=length+1
for i in range(12-coordinate[0]):
   print(length," . "*12)
   length=length+1
```

Length refers to the row number which begins as 1 and 1 is added each loop so the new row number prints.

I was wondering if there was a quick fix in order to, for example, scale down the row numbers so it will fit as one line; any fix like this would be functional. Any ideas of how I could quickly fix this indentation would be of great use. I'm a relatively new poster, so for any information that I may have missed out, just message me.

Comment: Please correct your indentation.

Comment: Note that the `str.format` method can help you create fixed width row headers.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to use [`str.format()`](https://pyformat.info/) with a specified width.  For example:

```
>>> for n in (1, 18, 100):
...     print '---|{:>3}|---'.format(n) # 3 is the width, > is to right justify
...
---|  1|---
---| 18|---
---|100|---
```

I wrote a short class to encapsulate your grid:

```
class SquareGrid(object):
    def __init__(self, size, empty_spot='.'):
        self._size = size
        self._empty_spot = empty_spot
        self._grid = [[empty_spot for _ in range(size)] for __ in range(size)]

    def set_marker(self, row, col, marker):
        self._grid[row-1][col-1] = marker

    def clear_marker(self, row, col):
        self._grid[row-1][col-1] = self._empty_spot

    def display(self):
        label_width = len(str(self._size))
        label_format = '{{:>{}}}'.format(label_width)
        labels = [label_format.format(i+1) for i in range(self._size)]
        print(' ' * (label_width), ' '.join(labels))
        for label, row in zip(labels, self._grid):
            print(label, ' '.join(label_format.format(marker) for marker in row))
```

Here it is in action:

```
>>> grid = SquareGrid(15)
>>> grid.set_marker(15, 15, "x")
>>> grid.set_marker(2, 8, "o")
>>> grid.set_marker(13, 3, "x")
>>> grid.set_marker(3, 10, "o")
>>> grid.display()
    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
 1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
 2  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  o  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
 3  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  o  .  .  .  .  .
 4  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
 5  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
 6  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
 7  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
 8  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
 9  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
10  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
11  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
12  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
13  .  .  x  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
14  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
15  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  x
```